# Extract file from corrupt archive

Tags: zip, archiving, extract, file-corruption

I am trying to extract a single large file from a multipart zip archive. The file contained is correctly identified by pretty much any tool used, but I didn't have much luck in extracting it.

Any program I tried either created an empty new zip (ignoring the file), or had that archive only contain a portion of the file (up to 5%).

Is it possible to extract entirety of the archive, either skipping the corrupted portion(s) of the archive or including the corrupted data?

Corrupted data is better than no data.